# Two versions of Emacs on MS Windows: change the default "emacs" binding in the MS Windows shell

Tags: microsoft-windows, default

I have got two versions of Emacs on my Windows 10 laptop: Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) and Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32). I would like the windows shell to run the 26.1 version by default when I type "emacs". At the moment, it runs 25.3.1.

So far, I tried renaming several variables in the registry editor, but to no avail. I don't want to continue doing it without understanding what I am changing...

[Update: I managed to make it work by going through the registry searching for any phrase containing "emacs" and changing some bindings containing 25.3.1 to 26.1. I did it for ones that seemed reasonable -- I did not touch any of the weird-looking binaries. No clue which one did the trick, so I am not removing this question.]